# How to generate an automatic bash/script

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I'm new to terminal and unix like systems. I'm searching a way to automatically create a batch file.

Let's say I have a bunch of files in a folder, and I want to change the creation dates. As it is now, I have to `touch -t 201704011215.00 Desktop/Old_cam_vids_converted_from_avi_to_mp4/file0001.mp34` for each file. What I would like to do is something like this: `ls -lT /Desktop/Old_avi_to_conv/*.avi` and have the date and time for each file as time-date parameter for the touch command.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:
I hope the explanation makes it clearer. This is the scenario:

- Two folders on the desktop containing video files.
- one (folder_1) contains the original files (.avi)
- the second (folder_2) contains converted files (.mp4)
- all the files in the second folder have a newer sequential date, since the conversion tool made worked through a list of files.
- I need to take the date/time stamp from the original file, in the first folder and assign it to the converted file in the second folder.
- each file in the first folder has a different date, possibly days and months apart.
- the files in the second folder have the same names than the ones in the first folder, except for the file suffix, e.g.: 
  folder_1/CIMG_0001.avi is the original of folder_2/CIMG_0001.mp4
  folder_1/PIC_0003.avi is the original of folder_2/PIC_0003.mp4
  folder_1/PIC_0015.avi is the original of folder_2/PIC_0015.mp4
  folder_1/CIMG_003.avi id the original of folder_2/CIMG_0003.mp4

Comment: You would use the `-r` option with touch, such as `touch -r /path/to/file.avi /path/to/file.mp4`. This still will not change the creation/birth time., for that you would use `SetFile`.

Comment: @fd0 thanks for that info. So is there a way I could, perhaps using "ls" plus the right option "ls -lT" create a list of the files in folder_1 and have the output as input for "touch" or "SetFile"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to process each `mp4` file individually:

```
cd folder_2
for m in *.mp4; do
    a="${m%.mp4}".avi
    if [[ -r "/path/to/folder_1/$a" ]]; then
         echo touch -r "/path/to/folder_1/$a" "$m"
    fi
done
```

Run once to verify that the generated output makes sense, then remove the `echo` and rerun.

PS: This assumes that the names of the video files don't contain the string ".mp4" as such.

Comment: The line `a="${a%.mp4}".avi` should be`a="${m%.mp4}".avi`.

Comment: @fd0 truely true. Feel free to fix any other errors you may find :-)

Comment: I don't see any other errors though I will point out that the variable in the extended brackets ([[) doesn't need to be quoted nor the `${m%.mp4}` in the variable `a` assignment. The `-r` test may follow a symlink  or for the matter any file system object. Overall a good answer.

Comment: @fd0 I know about the quoting, but it's easier to just quote filenames every time than to keep the special cases in mind.